# Running gunicorn with SSL on localhost? (with docker)

Tags: docker, flask, gunicorn

I'm developing an app locally in docker that requires ssl to work with an API endpoint and I've been having trouble getting these parameters to work:

```
gunicorn -c "python:config.gunicorn" --reload "dataexplorer.app:create_app()" --timeout 3600 
--workers=5 --certfile=/ssl/registry.crt 
--keyfile=/ssl/registry.key --ca-certs=/ssl/ca.cert --ssl-version=3
```

Docker cannot find these certfifles. So my questions are: Where is gunicorn looking for these certfiles? How can they be generated?

Answer (score 2):

Gunicorn is looking for the files inside the Docker container.

You can use Docker volumes to make your SSL key/certificates on your machine available in your Docker container.

Example:

```
docker run -v /path/to/registry.key:/ssl/registry.key:ro -v /path/to/registry.crt:/ssl/registry.crt:ro -v /path/to/ca.crt:/ssl/ca.cert:ro <your_image>
```

For development purposes you can [create a self-signed certificate](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ssl-certificate-self). In this case, you won't have a CA certificate, and you can reduce your gunicorn command to:

```
gunicorn -c "python:config.gunicorn" --reload "dataexplorer.app:create_app()" --timeout 3600 
--workers=5 --certfile=/ssl/registry.crt 
--keyfile=/ssl/registry.key --ssl-version=3
```

Answer (score 0):

It's looking in folder /ssl/

That's what this means: /ssl/registry.crt

It's looking in /ssl/ for a file called registry.crt Same goes for registry.key and ca.cert

If you actually have those files, place them where you think is appropriate and then edit the switches to reflect that location, for example --ca-certs=/home/user/ca.cert or wherever.

If you need certificates, you can create your own ("self signed") by following a guide such as this one: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ssl-certificate-self

Alternately you can get free ones (that need regular renewal) here: https://letsencrypt.org/

If you are willing to pay for them, you can choose from among a plethora of companies by googling for ssl  certificates.